# Best way to reload vc table view backing from another vc

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, segue, navigationcontroller

I'm trying to reload table view in Calculation controller, pressing back navigation button on Setup controller (red arrow on screenshot).
[image]

Which is the best way to do it?
Thanks !

Comment: Using notification center

Comment: viewwillAppear is the best one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a navigation controller its's pretty easy. In Swift the most efficient way is a **callback closure**, it avoids the overhead of protocol/delegate.

- In `SetupController` declare a `callback` property, a closure with no parameter and no return type

  ```
  var callback : (() -> Void)?
  ```

  and call it in *viewWill**Dis**appear*. `viewWillDisappear` is allways called when the back button is pressed.

  ```
  override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
      super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
      callback?()
  }
  ```
- In `CalculationController` assign the callback in `prepare(for`

  ```
  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
      ...
      let setupController = segue.destination as! SetupController
      setupController.callback = { 
          self.tableView.reloadData()
      }
  ```

Comment: Thank's @vadian! I guess, in my case callback property will be in setup vc. And prepare(for: sender:) method will be in calculation vc.

Answer (score 2):

#### Using Delegate Pattern

Create delegate with some method for second ViewController. Implement this protocol to first ViewController and when this method is called, reload `UITableView` data (in overriden `prepare(for:sender:)` set delegate of second ViewController to `self`). When second ViewController *will disappear*, call method on `delegate` variable of second ViewController.

Now when you're able to use delegates, you can easily add parameter to delegate's method and pass data from second to first ViewController.

---

```
protocol SecondVCDelegate: class { // define delegate protocol
    func controllerDismissed()
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "yourIdentifier" {
            let destinationVC = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
            destinationVC.delegate = self
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController: SecondVCDelegate {
    func controllerDismissed() { // this is called when you call delegate method from second VC
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    
    weak var delegate: SecondVCDelegate? // delegate variable
    
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        delegate?.controllerDismissed() // call delegate's method when this VC will disappear
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thank's a lot, Robert!

Comment: @butkovskiym no problem, I’m glad I helped. Also check @vadian’s answer, this is second option.

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution is to reload the tableView, when the view is going to appear again.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Alternative solutions could be to implement unwindSegue or delegation.

Comment: I agree. But since he doesn't make any networking calls etc. - I'm sure he'll be fine with this solution :-)

Comment: He does not mention anything about passing data between the View Controllers.

Answer (score 1):

to achieve this you have multiple solutions first of all you have to know what is the best to use by your case,

1- are you passing data back to the `CalculationVC`

2- do you just need to reload the `CalculationVC` each time it appears ?

for the first case you use what called **`Delegates`** in `swift`.

for the second case you can use a life-cycle function that is called `viewWillAppear()` in the `ViewController`.

for the `Delegate` case you can find tons of articles online [this](https://medium.com/@jamesrochabrun/implementing-delegates-in-swift-step-by-step-d3211cbac3ef) one  recommended for newbies !

and for the second case just use this code.

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code**

```
protocol VC2Delegate: class {
    func viewController(_ myVC2: VC2?, didFinishEditingWithChanges hasChanges: Bool)
}

class VC2 {
    private weak var: VC2Delegate? delegate?
    weak var: VC2Delegate? delegate?

    @IBAction func finishWithChanges() {
        delegate.viewController(self, didFinishEditingWithChanges: true)
    }

    @IBAction func finishWithoutChanges() {
        delegate.viewController(self, didFinishEditingWithChanges: false)
    }
}

//VC1: implement the VC2Delegate protocol
class VC1: VC2Delegate {
    var: Bool _needsReload?

    func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        needsReload = true
    }

    func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        reloadTableIfNeeded()
    }
@IBAction func displayVC2() {
}
```